# I can't see all data in the templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In my rider_detail.html I should be able to see a table with the rider's score, but I can't see it

my model.py:

```
class Rider(models.Model):
    id_rider = models.IntegerField(default = 0,blank= True, primary_key=True)
    [...]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.display_name

class Risultato(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (('SR','sr'),('ITT', 'itt'),('HC', 'hc'),('1C','1c'),('TTT','ttt'))
    id_ris = models.IntegerField(default = 0,blank= True, primary_key=True)
    id_rider = models.ForeignKey(Rider,related_name='rider', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_stage = models.ForeignKey(Stage,related_name='team', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type_ris = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES,max_length = 256,blank= True)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default = 0,blank= True)
    punti = models.IntegerField(default = 0,blank= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id_ris)
```

my view.py:

```
class RiderDetails(DetailView):

    model = Rider
    template_name = 'game/rider_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['risultato_qs'] = Risultato.objects.filter(id_rider=self.object)
        return context_data
```

my rider_detail.html

```
{% extends 'game/base.html'%}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ rider.display_name }}</h1>
<p>
    <h3>age:</h3>{{rider.age}}
    <h3>nationality:</h3>{{rider.nationality}}
    <h3>height:</h3>{{rider.height}} 
    <h3>weight:</h3>{{rider.weight}}
    <h3>team:</h3>{{rider.team}} 
</p>
<h3></h3>

<h2>          Score history</h2>
<table>
    <tbody>
    {% for risultato in risultato_qs %}
        <tr>
            {{ risultato }}
            <td>{{ risutato.type_ris }}</td>
            <td>{{ risutato.punti }}</td>
            ... etc ...
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

[screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC1jG.png)

I've installed Django Debug Toolbar to see if my queries were right, and they are. In fact we see 2 results one with 100 points ("Punti") and one with 50.

[screenshot of query results in django debug toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW9Cg.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, you are using `risutato` instead of `risultato`. Change it to:

```
{% for risultato in risultato_qs %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ risultato.type_ris }}</td>
    <td>{{ risultato.punti }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your loop. You can change your `loop` to this:

**`rider_detail.html`**

```
{% for risutato in risultato_qs %}
    <tr>
        {{ risutato }}
        <td>{{ risutato.type_ris }}</td>
        <td>{{ risutato.punti }}</td>
        ... etc ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Or the other way around as specified in Alasdair.